Unstable sound in Ubuntu 22.04
Unstable sound in Ubuntu 22.04.
HDMI is active and deactivated, inconsistent.
I want to disable HDMI and just use headphones.
But it keeps cutting out the headphones and activating the HDMI, uninterruptedly.
I uninstalled and installed pulseaudio, alsa. Sem resultados.
